# Stop method's execution - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, methods, delegates, watchkit

When my watchKit app goes to background it fires the delegate method `applicationWillResignActive`. Method documentation says it can be used to pause ongoing tasks.

I have an ongoing method that i want to be stopped or broken by the use of the external method. How do i do that?

**Example**

```
func method1(){
// performing some actions
}

func breakMethod1(){
// running this method can stop (break) the execution of method1
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `NSNotification`s to fire off at different events?

Comment: @dokun1 how do i implement NSNotification in this case? i have tried it before for executing methods, but not for stopping them.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you say that invoking `breakMethod1()` would stop it, yes? If this is the case, then use an `NSNotification` to trigger that. Is that not the case?

Comment: @dokun1 invoking breakMethod1 should stop execution of method1. can you please show an implementation.

Comment: @DavidRobertson in order to give an idea of how you'd stop `method1`, we'll need an idea of the implementation of `method1`.

Comment: @nhgrif it runs insertRowsAtIndexes with a specifically set delay for each Index.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36248081/edit) to include the actual implementation of `method1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, of course, assuming that your app has been architected so that `breakMethod1()` will definitely cancel the action occurring in `method1()`.

You should set up an observer for an `NSNotification` at the beginning of `method1()` like so:

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "breakMethod1", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

And for the sake of cleanup, you should also remove this observer after it's been triggered like so:

```
notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: that's exactly the issue - i'm not quite sure how to architect the method in such a way that it cancels the ongoing method

Comment: Then this is a bigger issue. You might want to consider rewording/re-asking your question entirely, as this is more of an app architecture issue. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish when the method is fired off. You should also consider the state of your app and how you might be able to preserve it when the app resigns from an active state. This is, of course, all shooting in the dark, since I have no idea what your methods do.